# How to extract special value from json using interceptor in Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have ErrorInterceptor which is getting error messages from .net core 2.2 backend. For single message it shows message correctly but for multiple messages it fails.I am doing something wrong in my typescript.

```
My ErrorInterceptor.ts :
  @Injectable()
  export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            catchError(err => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                    if (err.status === 401) {
                        return throwError(err.statusText);
                    }
                    const applicationError = err.headers.get('Application-Error');
                    if (applicationError) {
                        console.error(applicationError);
                        return throwError(applicationError);
                    }
                    const serverError = err.error;
                    let modalStateErrors = '';
                    if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object') {
                        for (const key in serverError) {
                            if (serverError[key]) {
                                modalStateErrors += serverError[key] + '\n';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
                }
            })
        )
    }
}

export const ErrorInterceptorProvide = {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true
}
```

Example of json file for single error which shows correct message:

```
 "Username already exists"
```

Example of multiple error message which I want to extract errors form that json, not title and anything else. To be precise error messages inside errors. I am using alertify for showing this messages. Json result:

```
{"errors":{"Password":["password is required"],"Username":["username is required"]},"title": "One or 
 more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"0HLRU5MDVJPEI:00000004"}
```

How to show exact error messages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your error messages resides on `errors` property and errors reside on arrays you can try the following code.

```js
 if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object') {
     const errors = serverError.errors;
     for (const key in errors) {
         if (Array.isArray(errors[key])) {
             modalStateErrors += errors[key].join('\n');
             }
         }
    }
```

Comment: It returns **[object] [Object]** Actually returns correct but shows like this